# My Seagate 1TB External Hard Drive's micro USB port is broken

Tags: hard-drive, connector

I have a Seagate 1TB External Hard Drive, Model ST1000LM024. It's worked fine for the past couple of years, but recently the micro usb port has been unstable and I've had to hold it steady to even use it. As my terrible luck would have it, the day I got a new drive and intended to transfer all my data, the usb port came clean out!! I know the drive itself is safe, but how to I extract my data without the original port?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to do it is to solder the connector back on. I can't tell if the connector is broken, but either way you should be able to acquire a new one cheaply (if this one is broken). Do you know how to solder?

Comment: I would rather take it to the lab. Yes, it will cost you *much* more than a new connector and a bit of solder. But at least it will work (given it is a decent lab). Actually, looking at the pics, you don't even need a new connector. The old one seems intact.

Comment: I think you mean SATA port. Yes the plastic is very brittle and easily broken. If you can unsolder a SATA SMT conn. from an old MOBO and connect to drive, it can be salvaged. Then reinforce with polyurethane adhesive and let dry for 3 days.  If you mean external USB port, remove drive and use SATA port.

Comment: @TonyStewart Why do you think it's SATA? It's USB. There is no SATA port on these drives (or at least no externally exposed ones)..

Comment: @Catsunami I have no clue how to solder. The drive itself is still intact as far as I know, but I don't believe the connector is - I think one of the golden strips is missing and I've no clue where it's gone.

Comment: take to a Pc shop

Comment: Are you sure this is an USB-only hard disk, and not just a SATA hard disk in an external enclosure with SATA-to-USB bridge? If I google for "Seagate ST1000LM024", I only get models with SATA II (Spinpoint M8). If it's an enclosure, try to open it up; if you find a SATA port, extracting data is easy.

Comment: Take off the silver tape, remove the USB adapter and plug the drive into your computer (or another USB adapter).

Comment: That tape is not "OEM" it is most assuredly an adapter taped to the end of the drive

Answer (score 6):

See if you can take the rest of the tape off.  The probability is that the drive is actually a normal SATA drive with a small SATA to USB interface board plugged in.  If you find that to be the case, then you can remove the interface board (unplug it) and get another SATA to USB adapter and just plug it in.  Many manufacturers sell them to move data from old drives to new computers - just lookup SATA to USB in Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting the drive in a new 2.5" external HDD enclosure.  They can be purchased very inexpensively from Amazon or your preferred retailer.

1. Remove the rest of the tape and remove the SATA to USB interface board (the green board shown at the top of the image).
   [image]
2. Put the drive in a new external HDD enclosure. Link to official Seagate enclosure on Amazon: [Seagate Enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0172A7NRI)

[image]

3. Continue using the HDD or transfer the data off.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video https://youtu.be/s0_zqKwax2M. You'll need to solder back the connector and fix any torn pads to make proper connection.